# OCMock: niceMockForClass expect zero call to method

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

In a test with OCMock, I must assert that no call is made to the `setState:` selector. However, I can make no assumption about the other calls that are made to the object.

Because any other call can be made, I have to (or do I?) use a `niceMockForClass:` instead of `mockForClass:`

How can I then make sure that no call is made to `setState:` ?
The code roughly looks like this:

```
- (void)testNoCallIsMadeToSetStateOnReset
{
    self.downloader = [OCMock niceMockForClass:[Downloader class]];

    [[self.downloader expectZero] setState:OCMOCK_ANY]; // <- how to do this?

    // do some stuff
    [self.downloader verify]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[[yourMock reject] setState:OCMOCK_ANY];`

Comment: Almost there, but... the setState: method's argument is an enum. `typedef enum { ... } DownloaderState`. It doesn't seem to work with OCMOCK_ANY. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do that, there is nothing like OCMOCK_ANY_VALUE. Maybe someone else can help on this... As an alternative, either you can use a normal mock(not nice) and stub the methods that are posible to be called on your mock, or reject setState: to all possible parameters.

Comment: Another workaround is to use a real object instead of a mock, and check directly the value of the state property. Before the code to test you can set it to a value that does not exist in the enum and after check if the value is still the same... You could also create a partial mock of this object if you want to stub/expect something...

Comment: That could be a good solution. I'll look into this. Many thanks :)

Comment: Use `[[[yourMock reject] ignoringNonObjectArgs] setState:0]` .  The ignoringNonObjectArgs is a new feature which basically says assume all non-object args effectively have an OCMOCK_ANY on them, so the values you use for the mock call don't matter.